# .NET Nested Classes

Tags: c#, .net, boo, nested-class, class-structure

The current class library I am working on will have a base class (Field) with over 50 specific "field" types which will inherit from "Field" and nested for maintain readability. For example...

```
abstract class Field
{
    public int Length { get; set; }

    public class FieldA : Field
    {
        public static void DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Did something.");
        }
    }
}
```

So far everything looks good and I can use the code as shown:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Field.FieldA.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

However, why does this work as well? What is going on here that allows the compiler / IDE intellisense to continue to chain these "FieldA"'s?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Field.FieldA.FieldA.FieldA.FieldA.FieldA.FieldA.FieldA.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

It's not application breaking by any means, but thought it was peculiar. Does the same thing in Boo (which is the actual language being used for the library).

Comment: Lol, that's actually pretty cool. Had to test it myself to believe it :p

Comment: Your approach is a reasonable one, especially if you want to control who can derive: make the base constructor private, and only nested types can derive from it.  I use something similar when I'm trying to simulate 'enum' behaviors with richer OO semantics.

Comment: reminds me of "moon instructs a student"

Comment: Obvious logic oversight on my part. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: An internal constructor would also limit who can inherit from it, too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you wanted something like:

```
abstract class Field
{
    public int Length { get; set; }
}

public class FieldA : Field
{
    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Did something.");
    }
}
```

Otherwise you're defining a base class with an inner class in it, which inheritorrs will also get. So when you inherit from the outer class to make the inner class, you're starting a loop.

Comment: Thats what I was afraid was happening. I guess Ill have to find another way of nesting my classes. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

1. `Field` has a *public* nested-class named `FieldA`
2. `FieldA` inherits from `Field`
3. thus you can always access `FieldA` from `FieldA`.

The reference isn't creating infinite chains, it is simply pointing to the same class. ([some test code](http://pastebin.com/f6d5f0e5f))

When you access `FieldA.FieldA`, the latter `FieldA` is accessible due to the fact that the former `FieldA` is an instance of `Field` so the latter `FieldA` actually access `Field.FieldA`

Answer (score 1):

FieldA inherits a reference to class FieldA which inherits a reference to class FieldA which inherits a reference to class FieldA which inherits a reference to class FieldA which inherits a reference to class FieldA which inherits a reference to class FieldA which inherits a reference to class FieldA which...

It works because *that's what you told it to do.*