# Is this C# compiler behaviour a bug or a feature?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

Why is the following code snippet valid in C#? This is a feature of the compiler or a bug?

```
class A
{
    public class B : A
    {

    }
}

class C : A.B
{
    public void Foo(C.B b)
    {

    }
}

class D : A
{
    public void Foo(D.B.B.B.B b)
    {

    }
}
```

#### See Also

> [.NET Nested Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455928/-net-nested-classes)

Comment: I don't see, why you included the C class. I think the question would be the same (and a bit shorter) if you removed it ...

Comment: Because C inherits from sub-class that doesn't have 'explicit' sub-classes. Weird in its own way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's legal code, but quirky. I can dig out the bit in the spec about name resolution if you want - but it's definitely legal. I've had a conversation about a similar topic with Eric Lippert before. Strangely enough, that used D.B.B.B.B... too.

The conversation came up due to [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265585/why-cant-a-class-extend-its-own-nested-class-in-c).

The relevant section of the C# 3.0 spec is 3.8, but it's too long and involved to be worth posting here.

Answer (score 4):

1. D is an A
2. A has a nested type B
3. B is an A
4. GOTO 2

Answer (score 1):

This is rather amusing.  I don't know how it could be any harm, though.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the code analysis guidelines state that [nested types should not be visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182162.aspx).